# Using Testcafe-Reporter-HTML prevents tests from running

Tags: javascript, html, automated-tests, report, testcafe

I am using [testcafe-reporter-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/testcafe-reporter-html) to generate reports from testcafe test runs and using the documentation provided in the above link for instruction.

The second step says `$ testcafe chrome test_folder/ --reporter html`

However, this is causing the following error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-e2e@1.0.0 test:debug: `testcafe chrome test_folder/ --reporter html:/path/to/test_folder/report.html`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

I have few test files inside the `test_folder`. None of them run.
But when I run an individual test using the following command:

```
$ testcafe chrome test_folder/my_favorite_test.spec.js --reporter html
```

the run gets complete and report is published.

Can some expert here help me identifying if my steps are following the documentation correctly or what is the reason for this error?

Comment: Could you please update your question with a full log that begins with the `testcafe chrome test_folder/ --reporter html:/path/to/test_folder/report.html` command?

Comment: Sharing the log in this file...

https://docs.google.com/document/d/134SHH_nxzvsSj9y7WsC4IG6rdPZHvFJgWLjUD4IhC0s/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide a path to a file or files via a wild card. Like so:
`$ testcafe chrome test_folder/*.js`

Comment: I tried that. But even that does not let write the report.

`npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! test-e2e@1.0.0 test:smoke: 'testcafe chrome test/*.spec.js --reporter html'
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test-e2e@1.0.0 test:smoke script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Answer (score 0):

The command below works just fine for me:

`testcafe chrome automation/tests/*.js --reporter html:tests/myreports.html"`